# List open dm-crypt LUKS volumes

Tags: luks, cryptsetup

If I mount a simple loop device,

```
losetup -a
```

give me the devices opened.
Is something similar possible with `cryptsetup`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`dmsetup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/dmsetup.8.html) is useful for anything device mapper related. For Example:

```
[root@localhost]~# dmsetup ls --target crypt
luks-90dc732d-e183-4948-951e-c32f3f11b305   (253, 0)
[root@localhost]~#
```

Comment: Is there any way to list all mappings with their target type?  The best I could manage was `for i in $(sudo dmsetup targets | cut -f1 -d' '); do echo $i:; sudo dmsetup ls --target $i; echo; done`

Comment: Thx. Getting the list shouldn't be so _cryptic_... `luksList` would be nice.

Answer (score 32):

I just looked for the same thing, a list of my luks partitions, though I wanted a mapping to the physical /dev/sdX devices.

I found a solution for that here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=164798

```
lsblk --fs
```

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that `lsblk` supports `-J` or `--json` to output the result in a machine readable format. Which can be useful when doing a reverse lookup of dmcrypt mapper devices *(`/dev/sda` -> `luksloop` for instance by iterating the `/dev/sda` children object)*.